# How to open pwa application from a web page (js)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA site.
Can I get link (`<a href='pwa:/index.php'>Hello</a>`) or something else to open pwa-app (has already been installed on desktop or mobile)?

Comment: If, on my Android mobile, I open a URL in Firefox Mobile browser which has a corresponding  PWA, the browser gives me an option to switch out of the browser and into the homescreen PWA. Is that what you mean?

Comment: And if you are already in Firefox mobile browser in your PWA site, how to get link to switch out from browser? Usually link gives a normal link to a browser page.

Comment: Yes. It's the browser itself which provides a button which gives me the option to switch to the PWA. It's not something I'm familiar with but you might look into Custom Protocols: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/hyperlinking-beyond-the-web/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers), [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler).